# .NET Core application on WSL2 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS cannot talk to RabbitMQ running in Windows Docker

Tags: tcp, rabbitmq, windows-subsystem-for-linux, .net-core-3.0

NOTE: MOVED here [from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1486946/net-core-application-on-wsl-ubuntu-18-04-lts-cannot-talk-to-rabbitmq-running-in), where it didn't generate any response.

I have a application built on the latest .NET Core 3 which was released this week. I am having a problem while running under WSL with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Problem is an exception opening up RabbitMQ communication:

connection refused 127.0.0.1:5672

Port 5672 is a RabbitMQ instance running under Docker on the Windows side. The same .NET Core 3.0 app connects to the port and functions fine running under Windows that WSL2 Ubuntu is failing.

Do I need to configure WSL2 in some way to open that port to Ubuntu?

- I can ping localhost and 127.0.0.1 under ubuntu
- netstat -a under ubuntu doesn't return much and nothing about 5672/RabbitMQ
- on Windows/powershell 'GetProcess -Id (GetNetTCPConnection -LocalPort 5672).OwningProcess' makes sense and returns docker...
- .NET not installed but the application was built with 'dotnet publish -r ubuntu.16.04-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed'

The code opening RabbitMQ as requested.

```
public MessagesManager( string channelname, string host = "localhost" )
{
    // real code passes username/pwd
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = host };
    _connectionMQ = factory.CreateConnection();
```

Comment: Are you using be any chance WSL2?

Comment: If you are using WSL1, try to allow that ELF64 binary in Windows Firewall.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks. I don't think the code will help, since it works fine as-is under Windows. Pretty much boilerplate Rabbit usage. IMO appears to be an OS/Configuration issue. More interested in what ELF64 binary means? I have punched a hole in the firewall for port 5672, BUT as I understand WSL2, both windows/linux are the same machine.

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez I am using WSL2.

Comment: I now see what is meant by ELF64 and will try even though its WSL2. I actually think this was working for WSL 1. TBD

Comment: You need to specify your machine's ip instead of 127.0.0.1. Because WSL 2 runs in a virtualized environment.

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez reading this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-ux-changes I think you're correct. I'll try Monday.

Comment: @kenny is there any solution to the question? I am facing the same.

Comment: @SayyedDawood in the end I did get it to work. I don't remember what the problem/solution was. I'm pretty sure I just create shared port but I don't remember the docker details. Sorry.  Sadly I haven't used docker since that project.